# Why are queries in the Google Search Console appearing surrounded by quotes?

Tags: google-search-console

I've been seeing this for a while now. Is it that people are actually searching with queries surrounded by quotes or is it like Google Search Console is showing that these were exact match queries or something? I just want to be sure.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Google Search Console Query Report with keywords in quotes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotation mark-operator: [ “keyword” ] can be used to search or filter for a specific word or sentence.

In this case the users are searching an exact match for "influencer marketing". When you use the exact match search operator, the number of search results usually become smaller as you are filtering and restricting the results in the first place.